# Configuring Symfony2 microframework as REST server

Tags: symfony

I'm configuring Symfony2 microframework as REST server. Does anybody know how to do it properly? May be some of you could share some tutorials ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [FOSRestBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html). It has nice documentation.

If you want some kind of boilerplate to use or at least get the idea, there is a skeleton project as well: https://github.com/gimler/symfony-rest-edition

I have used [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) for OAuth2 if you plan building authorization to the API

Answer (score 0):

What do you means "microframework"?

I hope it helps you http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html